# How do I invite friends from facebook using fb_graph?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, fb-graph

Basically I want to display a list of friends (with pictures and names) and invite them to my app I'm creating in rails with the `fb_graph` gem. The link shows the flow of how this would work, basically you would click an "Invite Friends" button and a list of friends would pop up with a button allowing you to invite the respective user.

http://www.quora.com/User-Acquisition/What-is-the-best-invite-a-friend-flow-for-mobile

Is there a way to do this with `fb_graph`?

Comment: Something like this? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/custom-muti-friend-selector/

Comment: Yes, but ideally I'd like to use the `fb_graph` gem

Answer (score 9):

You bet. Assuming you have a working implementation of fb_graph, you can get a list of friends with the following command (from https://github.com/nov/fb_graph ):

```
FbGraph::User.me(fb_token).friends
```

You can use that to generate your UI for your friends list, then invite the selected friends, like so ( untested modification from the previous link, as well as https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ ):

```
app_request = FbGraph::User.me(token).app_request!(
  :message => 'invitation message',
  :to      => friend.uid
)
```

The previous code also can accept a comma separated collection of UIDs.

I'll leave you to design and code the UI, but it is possible, using fb_graph, for sure. Those two links should be solid gold, should you decide to expand the scope, at all.

Comment: this isn't working for me. It appears that Facebook does not allow requests to be made via this method. All the requests end up going to the user who made the request.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your interest for my gem.

[Brad Werth's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12234341/525478) works for existing (= already installed your app) users, but probably not for new users.

There are lots of limitations to send App Requests in background to avoid spamming.
That limitation directly affect fb_graph's sending App Request feature.

If you are developing iOS app, I recommend you to use FB official iOS SDK.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/

Using iOS SDK (or JS SDK in html5 app), you have less limitations.

ps.
I'm not familiar with Android App development nor FB official Android SDK, but I assume they have something similar functionality in their Android SDK too.

Comment: I'm actually developing in HTML5 and rails. Is there a limitation to the gem that I don't know about with the way that @iioiooioo says? Also, what's the best way to go through the gem's functionality?

Comment: [The official document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#apprequests) says *"Note: POSTing to the Graph API endpoint of /USER_ID/apprequests is considered an App to User Request. App-Generated Requests do not receive notifications and get limited distribution in comparison to User to User Requests sent with the Request Dialog"*

`to` parameter in the @iioiooioo's sample code doesn't work. `to` is only available as the response parameter, not request parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Of course Facebook provides a beautiful dialog box to select friends that you want to send requests to. But there is also a nice tool, built in javascript, through which you have the same kind of Facebook Friends selector dialog box.

[JQuery Facebook Multi-Friend Selector Plugin](http://archives-mike.brevoort.com/2010/08/10/introducing-the-jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector-plugin/index.html)

This plugin will make a Graph API call to Facebook and collect your friend list. The advantage of this plugin is that it will load all the friends list in "lazy loading mode".

Answer (score 1):

This might be of some help, I used it on my PHP server and it worked.

This code helps you post, send messages, and also send requests to your friends.

**Head tag:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function logResponse(response) {
    if (console && console.log) {
      console.log('The response was', response);
    }
  }

  $(function(){
    // Set up so we handle click on the buttons
    $('#postToWall').click(function() {
      FB.ui(
        {
          method : 'feed',
          link   : $(this).attr('data-url')
        },
        function (response) {
          // If response is null the user canceled the dialog
          if (response != null) {
            logResponse(response);
          }
        }
      );
    });

    $('#sendToFriends').click(function() {
      FB.ui(
        {
          method : 'send',
          link   : $(this).attr('data-url')
        },
        function (response) {
          // If response is null the user canceled the dialog
          if (response != null) {
            logResponse(response);
          }
        }
      );
    });

    $('#sendRequest').click(function() {
      FB.ui(
        {
          method  : 'apprequests',
          message : $(this).attr('data-message')
        },
        function (response) {
          // If response is null the user canceled the dialog
          if (response != null) {
            logResponse(response);
          }
        }
      );
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Body Tag:**

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true // parse XFBML
    });

    // Listen to the auth.login which will be called when the user logs in
    // using the Login button
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      // We want to reload the page now so PHP can read the cookie that the
      // Javascript SDK sat. But we don't want to use
      // window.location.reload() because if this is in a canvas there was a
      // post made to this page and a reload will trigger a message to the
      // user asking if they want to send data again.
      window.location = window.location;
    });

    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<header class="clearfix">
  <?php if (isset($basic)) { ?>
  <p id="picture" style="background-image: url(https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo he($user_id); ?>/picture?type=normal)"></p>

  <div>
    <h1>Welcome, <strong><?php echo he(idx($basic, 'name')); ?></strong></h1>
    <p class="tagline">
      This is your app
      <a href="<?php echo he(idx($app_info, 'link'));?>" target="_top"><?php echo he($app_name); ?></a>
    </p>

    <div id="share-app">
      <p>Share your app:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="facebook-button" id="postToWall" data-url="<?php echo AppInfo::getUrl(); ?>">
            <span class="plus">Post to Wall</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="facebook-button speech-bubble" id="sendToFriends" data-url="<?php echo AppInfo::getUrl(); ?>">
            <span class="speech-bubble">Send Message</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="facebook-button apprequests" id="sendRequest" data-message="Test this awesome app">
            <span class="apprequests">Send Requests</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="user_likes,user_photos"></div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
</header>
```